# Why dont Input functions in python work in Bios Implementation Test Suite

Tags: python, crash, bios

Ive been trying for a while to test small python code inside of the Bios Implementation Test Suite and I've noticed that every time I try to enter in any sort of Input function it just crashes.

For example, if I type in the grub:

```
input("enter something:")
```

It will print out:

```
enter something:
```

But after that it freezes. Whats going on?

Comment: I physically cant as the second it prints it, it just freezes

Comment: It freezes because it's waiting an input

Comment: By freezing I mean, when I try to type anything in it just wont input. No keys work, and I cant exit.